# Look up table with fixed sized bit arrays as keys

Tags: c, hashmap, lookup, genetic-algorithm, lookup-tables

I have a series of fixed size arrays of binary values (individuals from a genetic algorithm) that I would like to associate with a floating point value (fitness value). Such look up table would have a fairly large size constrained by available memory. Due to the nature of the keys is there a hash function that would guarantee no collisions? I tried a few things but they result in collisions. What other data structure could I use to build this look up system?

Comment: well, a hash function can _never_ afford there are no collision as you reduce the amount of information that is provided

Comment: that said, the commonly used functions are sha1, md5, sha256...

Comment: I see, I have been reading about binary trees, it seems like they could be applied here but I am not quite sure how to go about that.

Comment: Would I be better off just grabbing some hash table from a library? I thought that given the structure of the problem there could be a more efficient solution.

Comment: well grabbing std::map from C++ would be an option IMHO, even if you need a C wrapper around it, it will be more efficient and bugfree than custom version.

Comment: How many bits per individual? How many individuals? Also: do note that a distance is between a *pair* of bit-arrays.

Comment: @wildplasser It depends on the problem, but in general each individual can be mapped to around  200*100 bits and the population size ~1000, however the archive would be much larger (at least ~100,000) depending on the available memory. The reason I am building such archive is because fitness function evaluation is very costly.

Comment: 20K bits * 100k entries seems doable. (about 0.5GB of tablesize)

Comment: `Due to the nature of the keys is there a hash function that would guarantee no collisions?` No, of course not. [pigeonhole principle] You want to push 20Kbits into ~30 bits. That just wont fit.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:
There is no hash function that guarantees no collisions unless you make a hash function that encodes completely the bit array, meaning that given the hash you can reconstruct the bit array. This type of function would be a compression function. If your arrays have a lot of redundant information (for example most of the values are zeros), compressing them could be useful to reduce the total size of the lookup table.

A question on compressing bit array in C is answered here: [Compressing a sparse bit array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232659/compressing-a-sparse-bit-array)

Since you have most of the bits set to zero, the easiest solution would be to just write a function that converts your bit array in an integer array that keeps track of the positions of the bits that are set to '1'. Then write a function that does the opposite if you need the bit array again. You can save in the hashmap only the encoded array.

Another option to reduce the total size of the lookup table is to erase the old values. Since you are using a genetic algorithm, the population should change over time and old values should become useless, you could periodically remove the older values from the lookup table.

Comment: Yes there are often only a small number of entries (e.g. 5 out of 500) that take a value of 1, the rest are 0. Do you have more specific recommendations for compression?  Regarding your second suggestion, it is indeed a very useful way to keep the memory usage under control.

Comment: Yes, if you need to keep track of only 5 bits on 500 you can save a lot of space with compression. I added some information on my answer.